# how to make activity draggable to dismiss in android?

Tags: android

[Like what google Photos has.](https://i.imgur.com/Mvs5E6l.gifv)

I've learned how to do the transition but can't find a way to implement draggable activity. The closest one I found might be swipe back, but I want the `Activity` or just image itself to be draggable like in the video.

Comment: try to play around new PopupWindow inside which you will get onTouch

Comment: @user1865027 did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Hope [this](https://github.com/davidmigloz/drag-to-close) library will help you.

Here is the implementation of this library:

Add Dependecies in you Build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.davidmigloz:drag-to-close:0.1'
}
```

Here is your XML:

```
<com.davidmiguel.dragtoclose.DragToClose
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:drag="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
...
drag:draggableContainer="@+id/card"
drag:draggableView="@+id/close_arrow"
drag:finishActivity="false"
drag:closeOnClick="true">

...
```

There are lot of attributes are available on given link.

This may not be the exact feature you are looking for but this may help you in your scenario.